# Dependency library after ant task in Maven2

Tags: maven-2, maven-antrun-plugin

I have a system dependency on a local jar which is compiled by a maven ant execution task using maven-ant-run plugin. How can I make sure that the ant task is executed before executing the dependency task. I am using system scope for a relative path where the jar is present after compilation.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't depend upon the scope of dependency, it depends that with which life-cycle phase you have bind the execution of the goal for any specific plug-in.

One possibility is to create a multi-module project with two modules. Module 1 should compile and place that dependency before building Module 2 (which will be having your existing project)